# Override previous application

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am having an issue with my application, where when I send someone an APK the only way for him to install the application is by uninstalling the previous one. Installating other application over a similar one works fine, just with this one. This is critical because lets say there is an update to the application, I do not want the user to have to uninstall the previous version before being able to install the new one, and should override automatically.

Below is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dooba.beta"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

       <!-- for card.io card scanning -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

    <!-- for most things, including card.io & paypal -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>




    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.dooba.beta.IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap = "true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo3"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" > 
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.UserDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">

            </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.EventsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">


        </activity>



        <activity 
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.CasualEventsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
             >
              <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />

        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.CultureEventsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">


        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.EntertainmentEventsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">


        </activity>

             <activity
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.introActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">


        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.MoodActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
         </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.ProfileChange"

            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">


        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "when I send someone an APK the only way for him to install the application is by uninstalling the previous one" -- why? What are the specific symptoms that you are experiencing?

Comment: The person in question is using a Note 3, and I don't think its a phone related issues because he is able to install new application over previous one quite easily, and do not have to manually uninstall the previous one to be able to install the new one. I don't know if there a function or a line I can write in the manifest that would automatically override the previous application installed so that user do not have to do it manually.

Comment: What specifically happens when the old application is not uninstalled and you try to install the new .apk?  I suspect there is a problem with the .apk signature key.

Comment: It gives me an error. A previous application has already been installed with a similar name.

Comment: `A previous application has already been installed with a similar name` then you are signing it with a different key.

Comment: For now I am using the unsigned APK stored in the bin folder.

Comment: and I do not want it to come across as a new application because then you would have both the old and new version.